# Newton's Law of Gravitation Explanation?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors

Based on *Fundamental Astronomy* by Hannu Karttunen page 318. It is mentioned that the planet experiences a gravity pull toward the Sun that is proportional to the mass and inversely proportional with the squared distance.
The book gives the formula as:

$$\vec{F} = \frac{GMm}{r^2} \frac{-\vec{r}}{r}. $$
How does the $\frac{-\vec{r}}{r}$ come?

[image]

Comment: Have you learned what a vector is? Do you understand what the vector $\mathbf r$ is? Do you understand the relationship between $\mathbf r$ and $r$? Do you understand what a “unit vector” is?

Comment: $$\frac{\vec -r }{r}$$ is a vector with unit length toward center of reference frame

Answer (score 1):

$\vec r$ is the position vector of the planet relative to the Sun.

$r$ is the magnitude of $\vec r$ (in other words, $r = |\vec r|$).

So $\frac {\vec r} {r}$ is a unit vector in the direction of $\vec r$ i.e. pointing from the Sun to the planet. And $-(\frac {\vec r} {r})$ is a unit vector pointing in the opposite direction i.e. from the planet to the Sun.

So if we multiply $-(\frac {\vec r} {r})$ by the scalar $\frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$ then we get a vector pointing from the planet to the Sun with magnitude $\frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$, which represents the gravitational force that the Sun (with mass $m_1$) exerts on the planet (with mass $m_2$). Putting this all together, we can represent the gravitational force that the Sun exerts on the planet by the vector

$\displaystyle \vec F = \frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^2} \left( - \frac {\vec r}{r} \right)$

which we can rewrite as

$\displaystyle \vec F = \left(- \frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^3} \right) \vec r$